# Rendering Ionic components from Server

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it Possible to render Complete app from a server ? 
Means only initial framework will be built as APK n rest all changed...?

My Understanding is that apk is quite similar to SPA ie pack and send to FE(user agent) Idea is to break this flow and render components like jsp snippets.

https://twitter.com/praveenpds/status/882844958012579840

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [ionic upload](http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/io-uploading) to update app view?

To answer your question, i do think it is possible, but then all the UI would be wrapped in a webview and then compile the apk.

For example https://www.appsgeyser.com/ allow you to do this. It just simply wrap your website in a webview.

As for the website of course you can build it with ionic then push it to the server and then just wrap the entire app in a webview.

One example is this website. https://m.stubapp.com/ (open it in mobile). Can easily put the url in https://www.appsgeyser.com/ and just compile it.

But then we have the [PWA](https://www.google.com/search?q=PWA&oq=PWA&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l4.560j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Where user do not need to install anything. But just simply add it to the home screen.

Ionic does support this. Refer to this [blogpost](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/).

After all in the end, it all comes down to the performance of the app. Hope this answer your question.